# How to pack message in Xcode5(SDK10.9) with protobuf for objective-C(2.2)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, protocol-buffers

I download ProtocolBuffers-2.2.0-Source.tar.gz from https://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers. There is a example in wiki.

It can get the packaged data use this way in the example:

```
Person* person = [[[[[Person builder] setId:123]
                                      setName:@"Bob"]
                                      setEmail:@"bob@example.com"] build];
NSData* data = [person data];
```

But when i compile my protobuf files in my mac, i can not find the method [person data].

It just give me a method writeToCodeOutputStream.

Comment: May be you need ask ProtocolBuffers author `For help/suggestions email me: cyrusn@stwing.upenn.edu`

Comment: :) may be you are right